# Set emacs to always run in background

Tags: emacs, x-windows, bash-alias

In my bash terminal I have emacs set to run in XWindows. I prefer this to not freeze my terminal session so I run:

> emacs *filename* &

Is there anyway to alias this?  I have tried:

> xemacs='emacs $1 &'

with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using `bash`...you can create a shell function by adding this to your .bashrc:

```
emacs () {
  /usr/bin/emacs "$@" &
}
```

It accomplishes the same thing as a wrapper, but without the extra wrapper.

Comment: That _is_ an extra wrapper.  The only practical difference is that once it's defined, it's stored in memory, rather than on the file system.

Comment: Yes, that is a more precise way to put it. I personally find it distasteful to have several one line shell scripts. With modern systems with plenty of RAM and disk space it is purely an aesthetic decision.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script to do that for you:

```
#!/bin/sh
emacs "$@" &
```

Comment: to protect arguments that have whitespace, use `"$@"` instead of `$*`

Comment: Thanks, I knew that, but forgot... updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** `alias "ec=emacsclient -cnqua ''"; ec my_file`

---

I recommend running Emacs in daemon/server mode, where it opens a socket and remains in background waiting for a client to connect.

The most common client, distributed with Emacs and immediately available, is `emacsclient`.

An important feature of `emacsclient` is that it can also start Emacs, in daemon mode, if said socket is not available.

To satisfy your requirements you need to start `emacsclient` with a few non-default options but this can be achieved using a shell alias, e.g.,

```
$ alias "ec=emacsclient -cnqua ''" # the void string '' is IMPORTANT
```

where (from `emacsclient --help`)

> ```
> -c, --create-frame      Create a new frame instead of trying to
>                         use the current Emacs frame
> ```

the above ensures that Emacs opens a new frame and doesn't uses the terminal

> ```
> -n, --no-wait           Don't wait for the server to return
> ```

the above frees your terminal

> ```
> -q, --quiet             Don't display messages on success
> -u, --suppress-output   Don't display return values from the server
> ```

the above silences as much as possible the client

> ```
> -a EDITOR, --alternate-editor=EDITOR
>                         Editor to fallback to if the server is not running
>                         If EDITOR is the empty string, start Emacs in daemon
>                         mode and try connecting again
> ```

the above is the key, if an Emacs server/daemon is not running, the option `-a ''` will start a new Emacs server.

You can kill the new frames using the window manager as you see fit but to kill the server you have to use the Emacs command `M-x kill-server`.